# Why "movies" and "television" fields are empty?

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api

Thanks for reading!

I have met a problem that when I type "me/movies" or "me/television" at the "GET" field on facebook graph api explorer, nothing shows up, just an empty JSON array. 
`{
    "data": [
    ]
  }`

I am pretty sure that I do have movies and television shows on my facebook account, and I did have access tokens for movies and television.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have `user_likes` permission which will give you the pages classified as Movies that the authenticated user liked. To get the rest of movies in the profile such as "movies watched" ensure `user_actions.video` is granted and use the `/me/video.watches` call